# SailsJS and mySQL custom ID name not working with blue prints

Tags: mysql, node.js, sails.js

I created a new model in SailsJS with a custom id name as the primary key. I'd like to utilize the blue prints routes that come with SailsJS but when I try to go to `/name/1` I get the error below.

```
ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause'
```

It appears that Sails is still looking for the default table name 'id' instead of my new custom id. Any ideas on how to get Sails to realize my changes?

Thank you

Comment: Just curious, since you are using a a column called `id` in your model, why do you need a different custom `id`?

Comment: @JohnGalt - I have changed the column "id" to "uid" because I have a relation in another table. When I try to utilize Sails default blue prints (ie: GET /user/1) I receive the error above. I would think that Sails would know to use whatever you set as the primary key in your model but it looks like it just utilizes 'id'.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Go to your model definition and add the autoPK:false at last.

```
module.exports = {

  schema:'true',
  attributes: {
    propertyName: { type:"string", required:true, unique: true }
  },
  autoPK:false
}
```

Comment: as someone who is just learning sails.js, this was a lifesaver.

Answer (score 5):

Okay I looked through SailsJS src and found in node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/query/finders/basic.js on line 37 that checks for the property 'autoPK'. This property is set to true by default and looks for the field 'id'. By setting 'autoPK: false' in my model it will check to see if you have set a custom Primary Key and will use that instead. All Fixed.