# SailsJS update and mySQL custom ID column not working

Tags: mysql, sails.js, waterline

In SailsJS, I created a model Profiles including a custom primary key as follows:

```
module.exports = {
  tableName: 'tbl_profiles',
  autoPK: false,
  autoCreatedAt: false,
  autoUpdatedAt: false,

  attributes: {
    user_id: {
      type: 'integer',
      size: 11,
      columnName: 'user_id',
      unique: true,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
  ...
```

Now, when calling the blueprint route to update a user profile, I get the following error:

```
ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'tbl_profiles.id' in 'where clause'
```

Debugging this down (and seeing question [SailsJS and mySQL custom ID name not working with blue prints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20874858/sailsjs-and-mysql-custom-id-name-not-working-with-blue-prints) not helping) I found out that the update is carried through all right in the db and that the record is changed but in the controller callback function an error and status 400 is raised nevertheless:

```
      Profiles.update({user_id: req.param('id')}, req.body).exec(function(err, profile) {
        if (err) {
          return res.status(400).json(err);
        } else {
          return res.status(200).json(profile);
        }
      });
```

Tracing down the SQL involved in /node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:48:14, it seems the following statement is executed just after the update is finished (note the final WHERE clause):

```
SELECT `tbl_profiles`.`user_id`, 
       `tbl_profiles`.`lastName`, 
       `tbl_profiles`.`firstName`, 
       `tbl_profiles`.`date_of_birth`, 
       `tbl_profiles`.`address_line1`, 
       `tbl_profiles`.`address_line2`, 
       `tbl_profiles`.`zip_code`, 
       `tbl_profiles`.`city`, 
       `tbl_profiles`.`gender`, 
       `tbl_profiles`.`country_id`, 
       `tbl_profiles`.`phone`, 
       `tbl_profiles`.`user_id` 
   FROM `tbl_profiles` AS `tbl_profiles`  
   WHERE `tbl_profiles`.`id` = undefined
```

Where could I set SailsJS/Waterline to use the custom column ID? Setting autoPK true either in the beginning or the end of the model wouldn't do the trick..

Comment: Yep, this is a pain in the ass, along with add autoPK false, try add `schema:true` and you might have to specify the database connection too but that combination has worked for me in the past.

Comment: Thanks Glen, unfortunately I tried this already without help..